# Add helm repo to rancher via cli

Tags: rancher

I'm trying to automatically seed a rancher environment with my own chart repository. I'm testing this with the rancher docker container. There's a 'helm_v3' executable in there but adding repositories to it does not reflect within the UI. There's a also a rancher-helm executable, which looks promising. It requires that you first run 'rancher-helm init'. I've created a volume for /root/.helm to accommodate the this but, upon completing the init and running rancher-helm add/update, it adds the repo and charts but they never appear in the UI.

Is there a prescribed way to add helm repositories to rancher via cli, specifically in a docker environment?